# Stancl\Tenancy manual install latest version

Tags: laravel, tenancyforlaravel

How to install stancl/tenancy multi-tenancy Version 2.X manualy without the command:

`php artisan tenancy:install`

I need to do it manualy becuase I have differant laravel setup structure

Followed v1.x manual installation but did not fit with v2.x